# comparing two dataframes results based on NA appearances in one dataframe

Tags: r

I have some data I would like to impute and check the imputations with the true value.

- I take the `iris` dataset (with no NAs)
- I randomly remove some results to produce NAs
- I then apply an imputation function to try and impute these NAs

Now I want to check the results but only check the results for the NAs. So I want to take the original `iris` data extract the values where the NA's appeared in the dataNAs and do the same for the `ImputedData`. Therefore I can check the `rmse` and other evaluation metrics between the randomly generate NAs which are then imputed with the true results.

Code:

```
library(missForest)
data(iris)
data <- iris

# produce 20% missing values
dataNAs <- prodNA(iris, noNA = 0.2)


ImputeDataFunction <- function(InputData){
  ImputedData <- missForest(InputData, mtry = floor(sqrt(ncol(InputData))), ntree = 100)
  ImputedData <- ImputedData$ximp
  return(ImputedData)
}

ImputedData <- ImputeDataFunction(dataNAs)
```

Comment: Are you looking for a subset of `Iris` that includes only the rows on `dataNAs` where `NA`'s are present?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `is.na` directly in a vectorized way and apply `which` with `arr.ind` to get the location of the `NAs`

```
i1 <- which(is.na(dataNAs), arr.ind = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can access the rows with NAs like this

```
NArows <- apply(dataNAs,1,function(x) any(is.na(x)))

iris[NArows ,]
dataNAs[NArows,]
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the variable name, original value and imputation :

```
NA_id<-is.na.data.frame(dataNAs)
comp <- data.frame(
  var = rep(names(data),as.vector(colSums(r))),
  origin = data[NA_id],
  imput = ImputedData[NA_id] )
```

```
> comp
             var     origin      imput
1   Sepal.Length        5.1   5.099827
2   Sepal.Length        4.7   4.506957
3   Sepal.Length        4.6   4.895653
4   Sepal.Length        5.4   5.243833
5   Sepal.Length        4.8   5.271015
...
```